# Save All Values of Database to Text File?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

I was wondering if there was a way to extract all the values of a column, and then save each value into separate text files (labeled ANYTHING, 1-100 works fine).

I know how to do this through another language, but I'm using SQL Server 2008 with Microsoft SQL Server Manager and it would save me some time from figuring out how to do it through C#.

Comment: Is it SQL or SQL Express? It's unclear from your question as you use express in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open a Data Reader and loop through each record
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx
- For each record, open up and write the column to a new text file
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

(If the samples in the links are unclear let me know and I can knock together an example)